# How to use SQLite in android fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-sqlite

I am an aspiring android developer. I wanted to make a simple project with SQLtite support, but I ran into the problem of SQLite whith Fragment.

Thanks in advance for your help

I tried replacing `context: FragmentTwo` with `context: MainActivity`.

It turned out another mistake.

Based on this, I concluded that this is not a solution to the problem.

```
class sql(context: FragmentTwo):SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VER) {
    companion object{
        private val DATABASE_VER=1
        private val DATABASE_NAME="GUESTS.db"

        private val TABLE_NAME= "GUESTS"
        private val COL_ID= "Id"
        private val COL_NAME= "Name"
        private val COL_CITY= "City"

    }
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        val CREATE_TABLE_QUERY = ("CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME +($COL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,$COL_NAME TEXT, $COL_CITY TEXT)")
        db!!.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_QUERY)

    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
        db!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_NAME")
        onCreate(db!!)
    }
    val allguest:List<guest>
    get(){
        val listguest = ArrayList<guest>()
        val selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME"
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                val guest= guest()
                guest.id=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ID))
                guest.name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_NAME))
                guest.city=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_CITY))

                listguest.add(guest)

            }
                while (cursor.moveToNext())
        }
        db.close()
        return listguest
    }
    fun addGuest(guest: guest){

        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(COL_ID, guest.id)
        values.put(COL_NAME, guest.name)
        values.put(COL_CITY, guest.city)

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values)
        db.close()
    }

    fun updateGuest(guest: guest):Int{

        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(COL_ID, guest.id)
        values.put(COL_NAME, guest.name)
        values.put(COL_CITY, guest.city)

        return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "$COL_ID=?", arrayOf(guest.id.toString()))

    }

    fun deleteGuest(guest: guest){

        val db = this.writableDatabase



        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "$COL_ID=?", arrayOf(guest.id.toString()))
        db.close()

    }
}
```

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:

```
public constructor SQLiteOpenHelper(@RecentlyNullable p0: Context!, @RecentlyNullable p1: String!, @RecentlyNullable p2: ((SQLiteDatabase!, SQLiteCursorDriver!, String!, SQLiteQuery!) -> Cursor!)!, p3: Int) defined in android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
public constructor SQLiteOpenHelper(@RecentlyNullable p0: Context!, @RecentlyNullable p1: String!, @RecentlyNullable p2: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory!, p3: Int) defined in android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
public constructor SQLiteOpenHelper(@RecentlyNullable p0: Context!, @RecentlyNullable p1: String!, p2: Int, @RecentlyNonNull p3: SQLiteDatabase.OpenParams!) defined in android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
```

Comment: @JohnJoe: No, it is not. There is [no zero-parameter constructor on `SQLiteOpenHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to a `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor is a `Context`. `Fragment` is not a `Context`.

Tactically, replace:

```
class sql(context: FragmentTwo):SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VER) {
```

with:

```
class sql(fragment: FragmentTwo):SQLiteOpenHelper(fragment.requireContext(), DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VER) {
```

However, in modern Android app development, a fragment should not be working directly with a `SQLiteOpenHelper`. At minimum, the fragment should be working with a `ViewModel`, which in turn works with a singleton `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Make sure that whatever books or courses you are using to learn Android app development are showing you how to work with the Jetpack/AndroidX libraries, including things like `ViewModel` and `LiveData`.